# What is static mass increase effect predicted by General relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, relativity, inertia

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame-dragging), static mass increase is predicted by Einstein's General Relativity. In the book 'The Meaning of Relativity' by Einstein, inertia will increase when the object is near a ponderable mass. I don't understand about the derivation of the effect. Can someone explain it further? Is it possible to amplify the effect to generate thrust?

Comment: Are we to assume you do not have the book in question?

Comment: I *do* have it, and the derivation is far too long to present in a post here. You're best off getting the book. I found a PDF of it, which seems to be legal. You're looking for Eq. 118 specifically.

Comment: Note that Einstein's "usual vector notation" is strikingly nonusual (this book is like 80 years old after all). $\operatorname{grad}=\nabla$, $\operatorname{rot}=\nabla\times$ and $[.,.]=.\times.$ .

Comment: I have the pdf. But i don't understand about it. If the mass is higher near a ponderable mass, then the stone will have higher inertia on surface of earth than on the sky. Why can't we use this to generate thrust? Like the Woodward effect? (even though the effect in general relativity may be much smaller)

Comment: Is this effect the backreaction of gravitational radiation on a mass?  It's true that a mass will lose energy to gravitational radiation when accelerated, but this effect will be vanishingly small unless the mass and acceleration are both large.

Comment: I wonder if this is just the GR version of the (rightly) reviled concept of relativistic mass i.e. gravitational time dilation means the momentum measured by a Schwarzschild observer will deviate from $mv$. The *static mass increase* would ascribe this to a change in $m$.

Comment: @JohnRennie: Yes, considering I have not read about this in any of the newer texts, I think you're right and it has been phased out of the terminology.